# Will I be able to understand how computer works when I finish electronic engineering?

Tags: computers

I'm taking a course that is focused on electronics but I'm not sure if it will cover how a computer works in depth.

**For Example**

- **I don't want to know** "X sends data to Y and store it, send to Z"
- **But instead** I would like to actually know how it works step by step starting from simple electrons flowing.

When I write a simple program in C how this relates to the hardware part... This was a big motivation for me to start the course, but I'm afraid that it will not be covered during the course.

**Questions**

- Under normal conditions will I be able to understand it?
- If not, is there a book that will help me understand the former?

Comment: Nobody knows that any more and as an EE I don't really care that I don't know.

Comment: You will if you want. To point you to books now could be way too early, since it seems you don't have the previous knowledge of how a processor works, how it communicates to internal and external buses, what is a cache, what is a pipeline, etc. And without that previous knowledge you can't understand Computer Architecture

Comment: So, the answer is no. I need to find outside the course, thanks.

Comment: The answer is, I don't know. I don't know what you know and I don't know what is there in your course. I, myself, learned all the building blocks I needed to later on deepen my knowledge in Comp. Architecture, in the University.

Comment: Check if your EE course includes "computer architecture"; if not, there are various online presentations on the subject such as "Nand To Tetris" which is quite popular.

Comment: How "electrons flow" (incomplete, misleading metaphor) equals "Solid-State Device Physics". Very specialized field, not designing the IC chips but designing the *process* that builds the chips.

Comment: All learning requires using models that gloss over difficult details. The level and subject of your models just changes. As suggested here, there are many subjects you can study. But don't confuse knowing another model with some sort of "complete" knowledge. The more you learn, the more you realize that there is just more to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding everything from electrons flowing (solid state physics) up through software is a big task. Bare minimum, you would need in-depth classes in:

- Circuit theory
- Digital electronics
- Basic combinational and sequential digital logic
- Computer architecture and assembly programming

plus a lot of studying and experimenting on your own. Microcontroller programming is a good way to approach this from the software end, while playing with logic gate ICs is a good entry point on the hardware end.

If you're asking whether a single course can cover all of these things, the answer is no. There's just too much to learn. If you want to get a vague idea of what's going on, you might start with a simple flip-flop-based hardware state machine.

Comment: I've read that even engineers that design the chips don't really understand how they(computers) work.  At least , that is what one hardware engineer that worked at intel said.  It was in an article that he wrote, in fact.

Comment: Nobody understands every detail of the transistor physics, architecture, RTL implementation, etc. But it's possible to understands the basics of transistors, logic, digital systems, and how they all fit together, which I think is what the questioner was after.

Comment: well, even technicians can understand that.

Answer (score 3):

In order to succeed (and excel) in the field, simply taking classes will not be enough. Something a lot of today's students don't realize is that simply taking classes and obtaining a degree is not enough.

I used to work as a lab technician at a university and one of the classes I worked with recently graduated, many of them with A's, B'S, and C's. They successfully completed all of their classes with acceptable grades and obtained their degrees. A few months later, they began entering into their career jobs. However, over the next several months I started hearing from them, and they were saying that they were completely lost and had no idea what was going on at work. There was a vast number of subjects that the work involved that are never taught in schools.

To make a long story short, what these students (and a large majority of current students) don't realize is that college/university requires a LOT of self-study, including research, experimentation, and exploration *outside* of the classroom. No college or university will teach you every possible topic you may need, they only present to you the basics so that you know how to find answers yourself.

I am certainly not saying that the classes aren't important. They teach you simple concepts and help you "learn how to learn", so to speak. You, as a *responsible* student need to work on your own alongside the classes, applying your newly-acquired knowledge to your own personal research.

Do not settle for simply finishing your classes and getting a degree. Instead, do your own research, continue your exploration, take on personal passion projects, and learn along the way. This is how you succeed and excel in the workplace, learning concepts that were never taught in school.

Comment: I agree with your overall point, but I get the impression that university standards have slipped since I graduated 35 years ago. After attending a 4-year EE/CS program, I had a solid grounding in physics (electromagnetics, metallurgy, semiconductors), math (differential equations), analog circuits and digital logic, and computer architecture/programming. I knew how to build a computer from gates (and how the gates worked) as well as how to write the compiler for it. In fact, my first job out of college was to design CPUs for a major computer vendor!

Comment: ... but it IS true that I had a strong interest in all of this long before I got to college. I had been dabbling in electronics since elementary school and in programming since high school.

Comment: I expect you're correct -- Many universities have indeed lowered their standards. Perhaps today's youth is lazier, and the schools cater to it? Flunking out of college will mean less $$$ for the uni, which is really what's important to them after all. Not education, just money.

Answer (score 2):

Electronic Engineering will give you some understanding of parts that get used in computers, but you'd have to be doing Computer Engineering to get enough of an idea.

Once you understand the behaviour of electrons (and holes) start learning about how the 0s and 1s are operated with Boolean algebra.

Read any book in the field you can find, which you find interesting you, e.g. IBM's Early Computers by  Charles J. Bashe, Lyle R. Johnson, John H. Palmer and Emerson W. Pugh

Answer (score 2):

Nobody comprehends a computer as a whole. There are layers upon layers upon layers. Educated EE/CE's understand maybe one or two or three layers, and have a working understanding of a few more. A real exprect knows one (maybe two) realy well.

I (as an example) have enough knowledge to build a simple computer from transistors up, and to make a simple compiler for an HLL downto machine code. That is a rather wide range of working understand, but I am not an expert in any of these layers. I wouldn't stand a chance in creating a transitor from raw materials, and I have only a very faint idea of the working of a transistor at the level of ions and fields. And I don't understand enough of a language like C++ or even C to make a conforming (let alone an efficient) compiler.

So I would advise you to

- get a 'faint' idea of the vaious layers of abstraction that are involved
- decide where your interest lies (helicoper view over a range of layers? in-depth knowledge of one or two layers?)
- study more on layers you selected

For the more electronic side read the 'bible': the Art of electronics. No need to understand everything in-depth, but it gives a good idea.

For the computer architecture side read Hennesey & Patterson.

Maybe add an in-between book on digital logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since we all went to different schools with different programs and within the category of EE there are specialties and perhaps you as I got to tune your classes you wanted to take.

You should come out with the "understanding" of how things work in that you get the physics to understand the electricity, you learn how transistors work as amps, but in computers are used as switches which is a far simpler use case for them.  you might take a class on the basics which cover boolean algebra, state machines and such.  How signals work across a wire, the harder stuff the analog.  digital is the easy stuff, until something breaks then it becomes an analog problem.

Armed with all those core tools yes you understand the pieces that go together, but that doesnt necessarily mean unless you took the right classes, that you have seen a processor work, they are not complicated, nor is ram or any of that with that core knowledge.  you can take auto shop in high school and can fix cars does that instantly make you a mechanic?  no, you have the core basic skills but some things come with putting those skills to use.

Here are the basics of a computer, from a digital perspective, which is what most of us deal with since someone else has done the analog.   one, zero, and, or, not.  That is it, if you can count from zero to one. and you know the three basic boolean truth tables, and, or, not.  that is it, that is everything.  processors are just a bunch of those things tied together, hard drives, ram, video, just a bunch of bits in a row.

Until it breaks, and then it becomes analog and you may have to go all the way back to knowledge from your physics or EE classes to figure out what went wrong (As well as all the tricks you learned from mentors the first few years out)

Comment: you actually dont need the full EE course, by the time you get to transistors your second year, you have already covered most of it, the electrons through resistors, caps, inductors, transistors, diodes, etc.  the make the ones and zeros, then it is one, zero, and, or, not from there.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - NO. This cannot be covered by simple course, it's often not covered well even in the bachelor programs.

I'd recommend you to find and read 'The Soul of A New Machine' by Tracey Kidder.

This Pulitzer winning book might look outdated (it's about building so called 'mini machine' at the end of 70-s) but is constantly reissued and reveals the entire complexity of designing and creating computer.

If you are still interested after that at least you'd be able to focus on some specific topic in your career.